# Can not get rid of autolayout! "Unable to install constraint on view"

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

I developed half my app with autolayout. Now I want to get rid of it. I only used it in the NIB. I disabled it in interface builder (the check box) but I keep getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint: view:'

I just want to get rid of autolayout!
Every 5 builds or so it works as expected :P

Thats the backtrace: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G3qXKL0Q)

**Edit:** The app crashes while loading the MainMenu.xib. I have never used constraints in code. I have searched the XIB with TextEdit and there is no match for "constraint".

**Edit:** This seems to be a bug in INAppStoreWindow. If I use NSWindow it works just fine

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. It looks like you are creating an invalid constraint in code somewhere.

Comment: No code of mine uses constrains and I have an exception breakpoint :( This crash happens when MainMenu.xib gets loaded.

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled the app from your device (or reset your simulator)? Have you cleaned your project with **Product** → **Clean**? Try both of those. Sometimes, xib updates don’t propagate correctly.

Comment: Have you tried deleting derived data? Window->Projects->Delete Derived Data